# Refreshing page for a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, jquery-isotope

I'm using the isotope plugin (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to sort and filter my articles. The plugin works well, but I always have to refresh the page so that the plugin works.
I'm using this plugin with Firefox. And here's my code :

```
$(function() {
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    animationOptions: {
      duration: 600,
      easing: 'linear',
      queue: true
    }
  });

  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('.grid').isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });
});
```

Comment: Here is the exemple of Isotope, http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/Ehgij
I've almost the same code

Comment: Works fine in the codepen link you shared.

Comment: Yes, the plugin works well for me too. But the issue is that the plugin don't work on first load, I've to refresh page and then it's working

Comment: Is it nested inside $( document ).ready() ?

Comment: Yes, i tried inside and not, and both don't work

Comment: "Almost the same code" means you have something different,so you should post it. Also, your link is to isotope v2 yet you are using code from v1 (animationOptions). Which version are you using?

Comment: Here is a fiddle of my code https://jsfiddle.net/6nL4nmm2/1/
I've remove animationOptions, it's working on jsfiddle but don't work in localhost on first load